# Java Scanner Input , there are no compilation errors neither successful input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The Following code is a simple java program where I am just getting an input of a student details but the program doesn't do anything it just stays like this no compilation error or does not take any input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scannerexample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int Rollno = scan.nextInt();
String firstname = scan.nextLine();
String lastname = scan.nextLine();
String Department = scan.nextLine();
Boolean Result = scan.hasNext();
char gender = scan.next().charAt(0);

System.out.println("Enter Rollno "+ Rollno);
System.out.println("Enter Firstname "+ firstname);
System.out.println("Enter Lastname "+ lastname);
System.out.println("Enter Department "+ Department);
System.out.println("Enter Result "+ Result);
System.out.println("Enter Gender "+ gender);

scan.close();

}

}
```

Comment: How are you running your program? You have no prompts, so the cursor will just be blinking while waiting for input.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. your program is waiting for input

Comment: Thanks Guys, it works as kiran said it is waiting for the input.

Comment: Consider using indentation to make your code more readable, especially if you are asking other people to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Each call of `scan.nextSomething` waits for input. So the way you have written the program you wait for inputting of all the fields and then print them. Try typing some fields and press enter to see the result in the end.

What you probably wanted is something like:

```
System.out.println("Enter rollno: ");
int rollno = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("You entered rollno: "+ rollno);
```

Also there are some java conventions which are nice and make the code readable :) For example variables start with lowercase and classes are in CamelCase

Answer (score 1):

So what your Code does is every time you call

```
scan.nextLine();
```

The Program waits for your Input, until you hit 'Enter'.

So if you want to write something before the Input, you have to do it like this:

```
System.out.print("Enter Rollno: ");
int rollno = scan.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter Firstname: ");
String firstname = scan.next();
// Any more.
```

Keep an eye that you only use **'print()'** instead of **'println()'** so that your input is on the same Line. 
Also use **scan.next()**, to only grab the input, and not the complete line in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

be carefull with scan.next() or scan.nextLine()

```
System.out.print("Enter Rollno: ");
    int rollno = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Firstname: ");
    String firstname = scan.next();
    System.out.println(firstname);
    // Any more.
    System.out.print("Enter Lastname: ");
    String lastname = scan.next();
    System.out.println(lastname);
```

in this case, if you input Firstname as: John Doe, it will not let you to input Lastname, because it will read next string in line.
scan.next() read strings up to "space", then another scan.next() will read next strings up to next "space".